# How to make the value typed into the editText a Global variable/string?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, global-variables

I am using Android Studio. I want the value typed into the editText by the user to be stored as an Global variable so I can then use it on a different activity (I am trying to make a basket, and the value the user types in is the product)
Here is my code for the first page with the editText called wood which I want to make as a Global variable):

```
public class Letters extends AppCompatActivity {
    int txtSize = 14;
    EditText Wood;
    Button bSize, bSize1, bSize2, bSize3, bBasket;
    public int count = 5;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_letters);

        Wood = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Wood);
        Button bSize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSize);
        Button bSize1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSize1);
        Button bSize2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSize2);
        Button bSize3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSize3);
        Button bBasket = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBasket);
        final TextView price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);

        bSize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Wood.setTextSize(40);
                price.setText("£10");
            }
        });
        bSize1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Wood.setTextSize(60);
                price.setText("£20");
            }
        });
        bSize2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Wood.setTextSize(100);
                price.setText("£35");
            }
        });
        bSize3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Wood.setTextSize(150);
                price.setText("£50");
            }
        });

        bBasket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               EditText Wood = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Wood);
                String str = Wood.getText().toString();
                if (str.length() == 0) {
                    Wood.requestFocus();
                    Wood.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                } else if (str.length() >= 2) {
                    Wood.requestFocus();
                    Wood.setError("You can only type one letter!");
                } else {
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Letters.this, Basket.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1: Add Extras to Intent**

```
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(Letters.this, Basket.class);
 intent2.putExtra("MY_INFO",str); // EDIT: putExtra() method 
 startActivity(intent2);
```

In Basket.java, in its onCreate method,

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.content_basket);
       String strFromActivity=getIntent().getStringExtra("MY_INFO");
}
```

**Method 2: Create static member in Letters.java class**

In class Letters, declare public static variable,

```
public static String editTextString="";
```

Add, after this line

```
String str = Wood.getText().toString();
editTextString=str;
```

Now you can access this variable by calling `Letters.editTextString`, from any class.

Comment: thankyou for your answer. When I type in  intent2.putExtras("MY_INFO",str); it comes up with cannot resolve method 'putExtras(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: Edit: putExtra() is correct method signature, if this solves your issue, please mark as answered.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to print the string?

Comment: `textView.setText(str); // replace textView with your textView name`

To print it in logcat:
`Log.d("MY_TAG","Passing Info to other Activity", str); // this will show in logcat window`